# XSLT replace value without copy whole xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I've got some *.xml with elements like :

```
<hl>
    <ho>
        <sh>At Vdara, you have a unique oppor</sh>
        <st>5star</st>
        <vi>15</vi>
        <vn>7500.00</vn>
    </ho>
    <ho>
        <sh>Experience luxury by design.</sh>
        <st>3star</st>
        <vi>20</vi>
        <vn>1000.00</vn>
    </ho>
</hl>
```

And generating new .xml-document with same structure and do some calculations.

**Output XML**

```
<hl>
    <ho>
        <sh>At Vdara, you have a unique oppor</sh>
        <st>5star</st>
        <vi>15</vi>
        <vn>112500.00</vn>
    </ho>
    <ho>
        <sh>Experience luxury by design.</sh>
        <st>3star</st>
        <vi>20</vi>
        <vn>20000.00</vn>
    </ho>
</hl>
```

I use the this XSLT to convert that.

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ho/vn">
        <xsl:variable name="arvalue" select="../vi"/>

        <xsl:variable name="val" select="number($arvalue) *  number(.) "/>
        <vn>
            <xsl:value-of select="$val"/>
        </vn>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Problam** is when increase the  tags XSLT transformation is very slow .sometimes It tacks 5 to 10 sec.

[image]

Is their any way to do this without **xsl:copy** .

Comment: If you want to talk about performance problems then please explain which XSLT processor exactly you use and relate the processing time (e.g. 5 sec) to the input size of the XML. And consider to show a profile relevant to the minimal but complete sample of XSLT you have shown, I don't see any `xsl:choose` in there, nor any `translate` call, for instance.

Comment: @MartinHonnen that xslt using with wos2esb. I don't know which XSLT processor i'am using. I use some functions to calculations  like `div - xsl:when -translate ` .I haven't show that in example. But most of the processing time goes to copy whole xml. when comes more '<ho> tags, more time to convert.That's the problem.

Comment: The `xsl:copy` instruction contains the child instruction `xsl:apply-templates` so it is very possible that your performance profiler is including the time it takes to process the child instructions when it calculates how long `xsl:copy` takes. So, you do really need to show a more representative version of the XSLT. Thanks!

Comment: To complete all the good comments here and answer your last question: **Yes, there is a way to do that without `xsl:copy` instruction**. Just use literal result elements and rules for each element `hl`, `ho`, `sh`, `st`, `vi`, and `vn`.